# how Can I I embed instagram code in flutter web project?

Tags: instagram, flutter-web

I am searching for a way in which I can include the embed code from Instagram to fetch public post and display it on my screen...I tried many packages from **pub.dev** like **flutter_html_view** and in this package, you have to run the project without null safety so I skipped it.
I tried this method too ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory () but there is no response and nothing to display to the browser.
so how can I implement this embed code and show it on the screen of my browser? please help!
[This is what is shown whenever I tried to fetch the embed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oSkd.png)
[This is the embed code that I meant which I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg7OD.jpg)